# android and googlemaps in webview

Tags: android, maps

I'm trying to do a pretty straightforward google maps feature for my mobile web app.
after some searching i found that just opening a href to maps.google.com?q=query in webview would show a very decent map. 
The mobile version of google.maps has a "current location" feature which i cant get to work. so i'm thinking it might need some permission, but i find so little information about it. Does anyone know how to get this function working? when i click the button, nothing really happens.

in my manifest i have this :

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-configuration android:reqKeyboardType="undefined" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_GPS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_ASSISTED_GPS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_LOCATION" />
```

And the entire thing loads in webview. Any pointers greatly appreciated :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns up that my webview just simply wouldnt allow me to do what i wanted. 
I ended up solving it by handling google.maps url's through device browser\maps application  within "shouldoverrideurlloading". Like so :

```
    if (url != null && url.startsWith("http://maps.google.com")) {
                mWebView.getContext().startActivity(
                    new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(url)));
                return true;
            } else {
                view.loadUrl(url);
                return false;        
}
```

And adding the intent to androidmanifest:

```
<intent-filter>
    <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
    <data android:scheme="helloworld" />
</intent-filter>
```

Answer (score 1):

did you added this library in your manifest.xml

```
<uses-library android:name="com.google.android.maps" />
```

Comment: hmm, that library would be for a native MapView, but it sounds like the OP is just opening a WebView to maps.google.com.

Comment: Yeah it's for just a webview opening a hyperlink to maps.google.com.
Found a working geolocation example which will work in my phone's browser.[link]http://experimenting.in/other/demo_geo_googlemap.htm
but it doesnt trigger in webview. 
ive added :
`mWebView.getSettings().setGeolocationEnabled(true);`
        `mWebView.getSettings().setJavaScriptCanOpenWindowsAutomatically(true); `

But no go...